# How to create a custom dialog in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view

I want to create a view like this
[Custom dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb1V7.jpg)

I am wondering if I can use a dialog to create this view. If it is possible to use a dialog, how can I position it to the bottom and make its height 75% of my fragment? Alternatively, if there is a better way, please provide some guidance.

Comment: Please use other resources like: https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/overview to identify UI/UX of interest.

Comment: You probably need `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Here are the implementation instructions: https://m2.material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment